# Installing flash player on Elementary 5.1?

Tags: release-hera

I have searched through a variety of resources (both here and elsewhere) and cannot find anything constructive or concrete on installing flash player for elementary 5.1. I was wondering if anyone (surely someone must have done it - and it's probably trivially easy) has any advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner"

sudo apt update

sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

The `adobe-flashplugin` includes support for both CHromium and Firefox.

Comment: In elementary OS, `lsb_release -sc` outputs `hera`. When using this command in conjuction with `add-apt-repository`, you're going to end up with bad ppa's in the sources list. For example, your command above results in `E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com hera Release' does not have a Release file.` So please edit your answer and replace `$(lsb_release)` with `bionic`, since elementary OS 5.1 is based on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: That's my bad. Wasn't really thinking about that. :p

Comment: Also, I've put the answer as community wiki. It'll need updating once eOS updates to the next LTS release which I'll probably forget/not be here for.

Comment: No problem, thank you for fixing it!

Comment: I've given it a shot, and the terminal returns the error that the command `add-apt-repository` wasn't found. Any ideas?

Comment: @ejb57 Yeah, sorry about my late response. add-apt-repository is part of the software-properties-common package, so sudo apt install software-properties-common before doing apt-add-rep

Answer (score 0):

This has instructions for setting up add-apt-repository:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-apt-repository-in-ubuntu/